# TFS 2015 installed widget can't be added

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We want to customize one of our on premise TFS 2015 Update 2.1 dashboards.
We installed a widget from the marketplace ([this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shanebdavis.code-coverage-dashboard-widgets)).

I can see it when I go to the "Manage extensions" page.
If I try to reinstall it for the team I want, it says: "The extension is already installed for this collection: {My Team here}. Select another collection to proceed.", so it is definitely installed.

However we can't add it to the dashboard, it doesn't appear in the "Add widget" popup.

Am I missing anything here to make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested installing this widget on my TFS 2015.3, it shows as expected. I'd like to suggest you upgrade your TFS to Update 3 and have another try.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer as confirmed by the extension's owner. https://github.com/sdavis3/CodeCoverageDashboardWidgets/issues/11